# Apache Spark with pip install not working

Tags: python, apache-spark, pip, pyspark

I'm trying to install Apache Spark with Python and used the pip install python command in the July 11 release. However, while this successfully installs and I can run

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
```

in a python shell, I can't access the pyspark shell by running

```
pyspark
```

or spark-submit, with

```
spark-submit.
```

The error for both is a 'cannot find the path specified'. I'm on Windows and suspect I'm missing the JAR files for spark. Shouldn't the pip install have taken care of this?

Comment: Please read http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2015/04/07/self-contained-pyspark-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pyspark` and `spark-submit` location (should be `<spark install directory>\bin`) are missing from your path.

You can run them by fully specifying their location, navigating to their install location and running `pyspark` or adding them to your system path.

Comment: Thanks! This partially worked, but ran into another error. I navigated to Python27/Lib/site-packages/pyspark/bin and they were there. However, how I'm getting the following message:                                              
`Failed to find Spark jars directory.
You need to build Spark before running this program.` Looks like I do need to build it with Maven, but I thought the whole point of pip install was to avoid that?? @timchap

Comment: Try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618843/why-does-spark-submit-and-spark-shell-fail-with-failed-to-find-spark-assembly-j).

Comment: should have Googled that second error. thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. If I answered your original question, consider accepting the answer by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Could you post the full path where you found the Spark directory after running pip?